# Hacked website, code is encrypted in hex, unable to identify

Tags: wordpress, hacking, hexidecimal

my web site hacked and i am getting code in index page, but i am unable to find that where is the code in my web site...

```
%3c%68%74%6d%6c%3e%3c%68%65%61%64%3e%0d%0a%3c%6d%65%74%61%20%63%6f%6e%74%65%6e%74%3d%22%74%65%78%74%2f%68%74%6d%6c%3b%20%63%68%61%72%73%65%74%3d%75%74%66%2d%38%22%3e%0d%0a%3c%74%69%74%6c%65%3e%2e%2f%20%72%45%64%20%58%20%7c%20%33%78%70%31%72%33%20%43%79%62%65%72%20%41%72%6d%79%3c%2f%74%69%74%6c%65%3e%0d%0a%3c%6d%65%74%61%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%22%61%75%74%68%6f%72%22%20%63%6f%6e%74%65%6e%74%3d%22%72%45%64%20%58%22%20%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%6d%65%74%61%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%22%6b%65%79%77%6f%72%64%73%22%20%63%6f%6e%74%65%6e%74%3d%22%72%45%64%20%58%2c%33%78%70%31%72%33%20%43%79%62%65%72%20%41%72%6d%79%2c%5a%6f%6e%65%2d%48%2c%42%61%6e%67%6c%61%64%65%73%68%69%20%48%61%63%6b%65%72%22%20%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%6d%65%74%61%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%22%64%65%73%63%72%69%70%74%69%6f%6e%22%20%63%6f%6e%74%65%6e%74%3d%22%5b%20%72%45%64%20%58%20%2e%2e%20%54%68%65%20%52%65%61%6c%20%4f%75%74%72%61%67%65%6f%75%73%20%5d%22%20%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%6c%69%6e%6b%20%72%65%6c%3d%22%53%48%4f%52%54%43%55%54%20%49%43%4f%4e%22%20%68%72%65%66%3d%22%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%75%73%2e%79%69%6d%67%2e%63%6f%6d%2f%69%2f%6d%65%73%67%2f%65%6d%6f%74%69%63%6f%6e%73%37%2f%36%31%2e%67%69%66%22%3e%0d%0a%3c%73%74%79%6c%65%20%74%79%70%65%3d%22%74%65%78%74%2f%63%73%73%22%3e%0d%0a%62%6f%64%79%20%7b%62%61%63%6b%67%72%6f%75%6e%64%2d%69%6d%61%67%65%3a%20%75%72%6c%28%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%6d%65%64%69%61%2e%73%6f%6d%65%77%68%65%72%65%69%6e%62%6c%6f%67%2e%6e%65%74%2f%69%6d%61%67%65%73%2f%6f%6e%64%68%6f%6b%61%72%65%72%5f%72%61%6a%70%75%74%72%61%5f%31%33%33%38%32%35%30%34%33%31%5f%31%2d%62%67%2e%67%69%66%29%3b%0d%0a%62%61%63%6b%67%72%6f%75%6e%64%2d%63%6f%6c%6f%72%3a%20%62%6c%61%63%6b%3b%63%6f%6c%6f%72%3a%20%23%46%46%41%35%30%30%3b%66%6f%6e%74%2d%77%65%69%67%68%74%3a%20%62%6f%6c%64%3b%74%65%78%74%2d%61%6c%69%67%6e%3a%20%63%65%6e%74%65%72%3b%7d%0d%0a%69%6d%67%7b%6f%70%61%63%69%74%79%3a%30%2e%37%35%3b%20%66%69%6c%74%65%72%3a%61%6c%70%68%61%28%6f%70%61%63%69%74%79%3d%37%35%29%3b%7d%0d%0a%2e%72%65%64%78%20%7b%74%65%78%74%2d%73%68%61%64%6f%77%3a%20%30%20%30%20%36%70%78%20%72%65%64%2c%20%30%20%30%20%35%70%78%20%72%65%64%2c%20%30%20%30%20%35%70%78%20%72%65%64%3b%63%6f%6c%6f%72%3a%20%23%46%46%46%7d%0d%0a%3c%2f%73%74%79%6c%65%3e%0d%0a%3c%2f%68%65%61%64%3e%0d%0a%3c%62%6f%64%79%20%6f%6e%63%6f%6e%74%65%78%74%6d%65%6e%75%3d%22%72%65%74%75%72%6e%20%66%61%6c%73%65%22%20%6f%6e%6b%65%79%64%6f%77%6e%3d%22%72%65%74%75%72%6e%20%66%61%6c%73%65%22%20%6f%6e%6d%6f%75%73%65%64%6f%77%6e%3d%22%72%65%74%75%72%6e%20%66%61%6c%73%65%22%3e%0d%0a%3c%64%69%76%20%73%74%79%6c%65%3d%22%66%6f%6e%74%2d%66%61%6d%69%6c%79%3a%20%50%61%6c%61%74%69%6e%6f%20%4c%69%6e%6f%74%79%70%65%3b%66%6f%6e%74%2d%73%69%7a%65%3a%20%34%36%70%78%3b%22%20%63%6c%61%73%73%3d%22%72%65%64%78%22%3e%2e%3a%3a%20%72%45%64%20%58%20%57%61%73%20%48%65%72%65%20%3a%3a%2e%3c%2f%64%69%76%3e%3c%62%72%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%69%6d%67%20%73%72%63%3d%22%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%6d%65%64%69%61%2e%73%6f%6d%65%77%68%65%72%65%69%6e%62%6c%6f%67%2e%6e%65%74%2f%69%6d%61%67%65%73%2f%6f%6e%64%68%6f%6b%61%72%65%72%5f%72%61%6a%70%75%74%72%61%5f%31%33%35%33%35%35%32%36%35%31%5f%31%2d%72%65%64%2d%78%2e%6a%70%67%22%3e%3c%62%72%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%64%69%76%20%73%74%79%6c%65%3d%22%66%6f%6e%74%2d%66%61%6d%69%6c%79%3a%20%42%6f%6f%6b%6d%61%6e%20%4f%6c%64%20%53%74%79%6c%65%3b%63%6f%6c%6f%72%3a%20%23%30%30%30%3b%66%6f%6e%74%2d%73%69%7a%65%3a%20%32%30%70%78%3b%6d%61%72%67%69%6e%3a%30%3b%74%65%78%74%2d%73%68%61%64%6f%77%3a%20%30%20%31%70%78%20%33%70%78%20%23%30%30%46%46%30%30%2c%20%2d%31%70%78%20%30%20%33%70%78%20%23%30%30%46%46%30%30%2c%20%30%20%2d%31%70%78%20%33%70%78%20%23%30%30%46%46%30%30%2c%20%31%70%78%20%30%20%33%70%78%20%23%30%30%46%46%30%30%3b%22%3e%50%72%6f%75%64%20%54%6f%20%62%65%20%61%20%42%61%6e%67%6c%61%64%65%73%68%69%20%48%61%63%6b%65%72%3c%2f%64%69%76%3e%3c%62%72%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%64%69%76%20%73%74%79%6c%65%3d%22%66%6f%6e%74%2d%66%61%6d%69%6c%79%3a%20%42%65%72%6c%69%6e%20%53%61%6e%73%20%46%42%3b%63%6f%6c%6f%72%3a%20%23%31%35%31%42%35%34%3b%66%6f%6e%74%2d%73%69%7a%65%3a%20%32%30%70%78%3b%74%65%78%74%2d%73%68%61%64%6f%77%3a%20%30%20%30%20%33%70%78%20%23%30%30%46%46%30%30%2c%20%30%20%30%20%33%70%78%20%23%30%30%46%46%30%30%2c%20%30%20%30%20%33%70%78%20%23%66%66%66%2c%20%30%20%30%20%35%70%78%20%23%46%30%30%2c%20%30%20%30%20%35%70%78%20%23%66%66%32%64%39%35%3b%22%3e%44%65%61%72%20%41%44%4d%49%4e%3c%62%72%2f%3e%21%20%53%65%63%75%72%65%20%79%6f%75%72%20%53%49%54%45%20%21%3c%2f%64%69%76%3e%3c%62%72%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%64%69%76%20%73%74%79%6c%65%3d%22%66%6f%6e%74%2d%73%69%7a%65%3a%20%31%38%70%78%3b%66%6f%6e%74%2d%66%61%6d%69%6c%79%3a%20%43%65%6e%74%75%72%79%20%47%6f%74%68%69%63%3b%63%6f%6c%6f%72%3a%20%23%30%30%30%3b%74%65%78%74%2d%73%68%61%64%6f%77%3a%20%30%20%30%20%33%70%78%20%6c%69%6d%65%2c%20%30%20%30%20%33%70%78%20%6c%69%6d%65%2c%20%30%20%30%20%35%70%78%20%23%66%66%32%64%39%35%2c%20%30%20%30%20%35%70%78%20%23%66%66%32%64%39%35%3b%22%3e%72%65%64%2d%78%40%68%61%63%6b%65%72%6d%61%69%6c%2e%63%6f%6d%3c%2f%64%69%76%3e%0d%0a%3c%62%72%2f%3e%3c%64%69%76%20%73%74%79%6c%65%3d%22%66%6f%6e%74%2d%73%69%7a%65%3a%20%32%30%70%78%3b%22%3e%2e%2e%3a%3a%7c%20%47%72%65%65%74%7a%20%7c%3a%3a%2e%2e%3c%2f%64%69%76%3e%0d%0a%3c%64%69%76%20%73%74%79%6c%65%3d%22%66%6f%6e%74%2d%66%61%6d%69%6c%79%3a%20%42%6f%6f%6b%20%41%6e%74%69%71%75%61%3b%63%6f%6c%6f%72%3a%20%67%72%65%79%3b%66%6f%6e%74%2d%73%69%7a%65%3a%20%32%30%70%78%3b%74%65%78%74%2d%73%68%61%64%6f%77%3a%20%72%65%64%20%31%70%78%20%2d%30%70%78%20%36%70%78%22%3e%2e%3a%3a%20%78%33%6f%2d%31%33%33%37%20%7c%20%47%61%62%62%79%20%7c%20%24%70%21%72%21%74%7e%24%33%33%6b%33%72%20%7c%20%46%72%45%61%4b%79%20%3a%3a%2e%3c%62%72%2f%3e%41%6c%6c%20%4d%65%6d%62%65%72%73%20%6f%66%20%33%78%70%31%72%33%20%43%79%62%65%72%20%41%72%6d%79%3c%2f%64%69%76%3e%3c%62%72%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%65%6d%62%65%64%20%73%72%63%3d%22%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%79%6f%75%74%75%62%65%2e%67%6f%6f%67%6c%65%61%70%69%73%2e%63%6f%6d%2f%76%2f%70%74%5a%31%77%6f%33%4a%73%50%63%26%61%75%74%6f%70%6c%61%79%3d%31%26%6c%6f%6f%70%3d%31%22%20%74%79%70%65%3d%22%61%70%70%6c%69%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2f%78%2d%73%68%6f%63%6b%77%61%76%65%2d%66%6c%61%73%68%22%20%77%6d%6f%64%65%3d%22%74%72%61%6e%73%70%61%72%65%6e%74%22%20%77%69%64%74%68%3d%22%31%22%20%68%65%69%67%68%74%3d%22%31%22%3e%3c%2f%62%6f%64%79%3e%3c%2f%68%74%6d%6c%3e'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting chars to hex is not really encryption. Converted back to ASCII characters it's just a regular html document, letting you know who the hackers are:

```
<html><head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>./rEdX|3xp1r3CyberArmy</title>
<meta name="author" content="rEdX"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="rEdX, 3xp1r3CyberArmy, Zone-H, Bangladeshi Hacker"/>
<meta name="description" content="[rEdX..TheRealOutrageous]"/>
<link rel="SHORTCUTICON" href="http://us.yimg.com/i/mesg/emoticons7/61.gif">
<style type="text/css">
body{ 
background-image:url(http://media.somewhereinblog.net/images/ondhokarer_rajputra_1338250431_1-bg.gif);
background-color:black;
color:#FFA500;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
}
img{
opacity:0.75;
filter:alpha(opacity=75);
}
.redx{
text-shadow: 0 0 6px red, 0 0 5px red, 0 0 5px red;
color: #FFF
}
</style>
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="returnfalse" onkeydown="returnfalse" onmousedown="returnfalse">
<div style="font-family: Palatino Linotype; font-size:46px;" class="redx">.::rEdXWasHere::.</div><br/>
<img src="http://media.somewhereinblog.net/images/ondhokarer_rajputra_1353552651_1-red-x.jpg"><br/>
<div style="font-family: Bookman Old Style; color:#000; font-size:20px; margin:0; text-shadow: 0 1px 3px #00FF00, -1px 0 3px #00FF00, 0 -1px 3px #00FF00, 1px 0 3px #00FF00;">Proud To be a Bangladeshi Hacker</div><br/>
<div style="font-family: Berlin Sans FB; color:#151B54; font-size:20px; text-shadow: 0 0 3px #00FF00, 0 0 3px #00FF00, 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 5px #F00, 0 0 5px #ff2d95;">Dear ADMIN<br/>!Secure your SITE!</div><br/>
<div style="font-size:18px; font-family: Century Gothic; color:#000; text-shadow: 0 0 3px lime, 0 0 3px lime, 0 0 5px #ff2d95, 0 0 5px #ff2d95;">red-x@hackermail.com</div>
<br/><div style="font-size:20px;">..::|Greetz|::..</div>
<div style="font-family: Book Antiqua; color:grey; font-size:20px; text-shadow: red 1px -0px 6px">.::x3o-1337|Gabby|$p!r!t~$33k3r|FrEaKy::.<br/>All Members of 3xp1r3 Cyber Army</div><br/>
<embed src="http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/ptZ1wo3JsPc&autoplay=1&loop=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="1" height="1"></body></html>
```

Comment: i get it, but match of this coding is not in any of page in my site. how i will find it?

Comment: Ehhh what? When you browse your sites index page in a browser, the string "%3c%68%74%6d%6c%3e%3c..." is displayed, but when you open the file on the server there's nothing like it in the actual file?

Comment: yes,,, i search in every php and js file ,, i cant find it..

Comment: It's not unusual for php exploits to obfuscate statements in more than one turn. In that case `eval()` is often used to expand and execute the obfuscated payload. Look for `eval(` instead, or code that fetches external resources

Comment: @dhakad Ultimately it doesn't *matter* where the code is (unless you don't have a known-good backup prior to the compromise and need to scrub your live code to restore to the machine after you rebuild from this compromise…) -- What matters is determining *how they got in* so you can close that hole during your rebuild...